# Where is the FQDN on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to migrate my SQL Server 2008 database to Azure, but I can't find the FQDN to connect from SQL Server Management Studio. I've been searching for two days and found nothing. On the web interface (https://manage.windowsazure.com/), google, and all other place. Everyone just assumes that the reader know where the FQDN is.

I've tried `servername.database.windows.net`, the "Manage URL" link from Azure web interface which both fails. Database firewall has been set to allow my current IP address. Where can I get the FQDN to connect to the sql database?

I need this because I'm doing a database-first development with ASP.Net MVC3 as opposed to code-first. It would really helpful if there's a tutorial on deploying that too (because I only found tutorials for code-first development).

Thanks before.

Comment: `[YOUR_SERVER_NAME].database.windows.net` is correct, at least when compared to my connection. I would look for some other issue preventing you from connecting.

Comment: What version of SQL Server Mgmt Studio are you using, you need to use 2008 R2 SP1 or 2012?

Comment: @user728584 I am using SQL Management Studio 2008 R2 SP1

Comment: @JcFx what is the best way to check the connection issue?

Comment: OK, just validate everything here for sanity check "BIG FLASHING NOTE section" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peterlau/archive/2012/02/28/get-started-with-sql-azure-resources.aspx Also is it possible to try from another machine to rule out environment issues?

Comment: @bertzzie If you've got the correct version of SSMS then my hunch would be that this is a firewall thing. Try wireshark maybe - something that lets you monitor network traffic? I'm a coder more than a DBA or server admin, so it's not really my field. Perhaps your IP has changed? Or your local firewall is stopping outbound connections? Maybe this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621782.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have correct SQL Database FQDN name as shown above and your connectivity problem is not related with FQDN name so you would need to troubleshoot the connectivity issues first.

The following article provides a wide verity of steps to troubleshoot the problems:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1719.windows-azure-sql-database-connectivity-troubleshooting-guide.aspx